# YouTube Data API get sub list returning incorect data

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)

Using the API Explorer on the site am trying to get my subscription list

```
channelid=UCi-Zy3O4CWziq9OZW-Al_9w
```

The channel as 20 sub am only getting 1 result and this of my other YouTube account

```
"channelId": "UCsOIinNuWBsSnJinahMj4zA" <-- other youtube channelid(i have 2 accounts)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have a PHP page that pulling the data from the YouTube API it is also getting the same results I am hoping that someone can understand why this not working on the dev website I could fix it.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&channelId=UCi-Zy3O4CWziq9OZW-Al_9w&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Response:

```
   200 OK
- SHOW HEADERS -
{
 "kind": "youtube#subscriptionListResponse",
 "etag": "\"abQHWywil_AkNqdqji7_FqiK-u4/Y43qe50CL23jmTwYBVjdLwyJYRg\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#subscription",
   "etag": "\"abQHWywil_AkNqdqji7_FqiK-u4/PaB4qya_oeOGHQb8uJxncbv0u04\"",
   "id": "alguZF2ihtTJA3RmYICZ0VEKIsdsOa--vVjTTNEet0U",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-01-24T17:18:55.000Z",
    "title": "Asaf David",
    "description": "",
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#channel",
     "channelId": "UCsOIinNuWBsSnJinahMj4zA"
    },
    "channelId": "UCi-Zy3O4CWziq9OZW-Al_9w",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/--cBdfTckJ8I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OsBikVPvwpk/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/--cBdfTckJ8I/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/OsBikVPvwpk/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg"
     }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Edit:
I dont understand why but if i remove the channelid it seem to be working
 `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&mySubscribers=true&fields=items%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
 can anyone explain this?
 allso is there a way to sort by most recent?

2 Edit:
one more problem the output is wrong the first 5 names are fine and following
 pages hold copy of names that allrdy showd or have less then 5 names
i testd it on the website geting same output i really dont know what am doing wrong from channelid not being used/or accepted to random output of names from the sub list
output subs:

```
YouReNext HD
TheRealDocM88
King-Of-_Spades
2p Italy ahetalianperson
JackJapoolGaming
"nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
2p Italy ahetalianperson <-- copy allrdy posted
JackJapoolGaming <-- copy allrdy posted
kiwi gaming ex
Jirou Namakii
SpiderGs
"nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
JackJapoolGaming <-- copy allrdy posted
kiwi gaming ex <-- copy allrdy posted
Jirou Namakii <-- copy allrdy posted
"nextPageToken": "CA8QAA",
kiwi gaming ex <-- copy allrdy posted
Jirou Namakii <-- copy allrdy posted
SpiderGs  <-- copy allrdy posted
```

Comment: When did you subscribe to those channels? Maybe that data is not updated instantly, your queries look correct to me (tried on my own channel and it works)

Comment: Welcome to stack.  Please remember to format  your questions correctly.   Spelling, grammar and punctuation should at least be attempted.

Comment: " chrki When did you subscribe to those channels?"  err am trying to get a list of ppl that sub to my channel not a list of ppl that i sub to ,omg is this totally the wrong http request?

Comment: i dont understand why but if i remove the channelid it seem to be working  -GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&mySubscribers=true&fields=items%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}  can anyone explain this? allso is there a way to sort by most recent?